# python code to get (latest) file with timestamp as name to attach to a e-mail

Tags: python, bash, email-attachments

1. I have a BASH script that takes a photo with a webcam.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # datum (in swedish) = date

   datum=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M')

   fswebcam -r --no-banner /home/pi/webcam/$datum.jpg
   ```
2. I have a python code to take run the BASH script when recieve a signal from a motion detector and also call a module wich send the e-mail

   ```
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
   import time
   import gray_camera
   import python_security_mail

   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

   while True:
       if(GPIO.input (23)== 1):
           print('discovered!!!')
           gray_camera.camera()
       time.sleep(1)
       python_security_mail.mail()
       time.sleep(1.5)
   GPIO.cleanup()
   ```

And the mail code:

```
    import os
    import smtplib
    import userpass
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

    def SendMail(ImgFileName):
        img_data = open('/home/pi/solstol.png', 'rb').read() 
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
        msg['From'] = userpass.fromaddr
        msg['To'] = userpass.toaddr
    fromaddr = userpass.fromaddr
    toaddr = userpass.toaddr

    text = MIMEText("test")
    msg.attach(text)
    image = MIMEImage(img_data, name=os.path.basename('/home/pi/solstol.png'))  
    msg.attach(image)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.ehlo()
    s.login(fromaddr, userpass.password)
    s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

I have just learned how to attach a file to a e-mail.
The code works so far. But I would like to get the latest photo taken and attach to the email.

I am still just a beginner in Python. The code in here I have mostly copied from various tutorials and changed a little bit to work for me. I have no deep understanding in all of this. In some few parts I may perhaps have intemediate knowledge.
I have no idea how to write the code to get python to find the file (photo with jpg format) I want and attach it to the mail.

So I am very glad if there is someone who can guide me how to fill in the missing part.

---

I put in wrong code for the mail function. I got a little bit better result with this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import userpass
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

def send_a_picture():
    gmail_user = userpass.fromaddr
    gmail_pwd = userpass.password

    def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
       msg = MIMEMultipart()

       msg['From'] = gmail_user
       msg['To'] = userpass.toaddr
       msg['Subject'] = subject

       msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

       part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
       part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
       Encoders.encode_base64(part)
       part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
       msg.attach(part)

       mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.starttls()
       mailServer.ehlo()
       mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
       mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
       mailServer.close()

    mail(userpass.toaddr,
       "One step further",
       "Hello. Thanks for the link. I am a bit closer now.",
       "solstol.png")


send_a_picture()
```

Edit.

Hello. I have now added seconds to the filename. If there is no picture in the folder when running glob.glob("/home/pi/*.jgp") I got: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    last_photo_taken = glob.glob("/home/pi/*.jpg")[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range.

When I take a picture I got a return ('/home/pi/2017-01-16-23:39:46.jpg'). 
If I then takes another picture the return still is '/home/pi/2017-01-16-23:39:46.jpg'. 
If I restart the shell I got the next picture as return. Thank you for your help  today. I will write more tomorow.

Comment: I was sorry to reject your edit to my answer, even if it was very kind, and I appreciate it, but as a SO rule, you cannot edit answers to add "thanks". Just accept whichever answer you find the best. Don't worry, it's not a problem. Everyone has to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of some code to list all files and folders in a specific folder:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("myfolder")
```

And here's one way to take that list and filter for names that match a specific regular expression (I've used filenames of the format YYYYMMDD-HHMM.jpg, but you can change that):

```
import re
jpgre = re.compile(r"\d{8}-\d{4}\.jpg")
jpgs = [s for s in files if jpgre.match(s)]
```

Now we need to sort by date/time because the list is in arbitrary order. Note that all my filenames are of the form YYYYMMDD-HHMM.jpg, so we can easily sort it by date/time, as follows:

```
jpgs.sort()
```

And finally, the newest JPG filename is the last in the list:

```
file = jpgs[-1]
```

Hope this gets you started. Note that I've assumed that you may have other JPGs in the same folder so a listing of *.jpg might yield undesirable files,  and that's why I gave a general solution using regular expression matching. If you don't have other JPGs then you could use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)("folder/*.jpg").

Comment: Thank you all for fast reply. I will test this as soon as I can. Have not som much spare time (two small children at home). But I will tell how I have progress with this.

Comment: Hello. The first part in your answer was no problem. I got all files in the folder listed (os.listdir('myfolder')). The next one I could not get working for me. I have to study how to use it. I have no idea what "(r"\d{8}-\d{4}\." does. So I dont know whats cause error in my case. But I will not give up.

Comment: For your format, you can use r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}\.jpg". Note that \d{4} means four digits, \d{2} means two digits etc. You're matching filenames of the form 4 digits, hyphen, 2 digits, hyphen, 2 digits, hyphen, 2 digits, colon, 2 digits, and finally .jpg.

Comment: I will test this tonight. I added seconds to the filename.

Comment: :-) It works :-) It was the format that I had to change. Thank you very much for excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2):

the format you chose `'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M'` has the nice property to have the same sort order alphabetically or date-wise.

So since your files are located in `/home/pi/webcam` and have the jpg extension, you could compute the last photo like this:

```
import glob
last_photo_taken = glob.glob("/home/pi/webcam/*.jpg")[-1]
```

Attach the `last_photo_taken` file to your e-mail.

Note: photos taken at the same minute will overlap: last photo overwrites the previous one. You should consider adding seconds to the file name.

Note: even if your files weren't conveniently named with the date, you could sort the images by modification date and take the last one:

```
last_photo_taken = sorted(glob.glob("/home/pi/webcam/*.jpg"),key=os.path.getmtime)[-1]
```

Comment: Hi. The "last_photo_taken" variable do find a file. But no the last one. If I take more pictures it still return the same result I got when I run the code the first time. Is there some kind of update/refresh I have to do to get the last photo taken? The secon code did not work for me at all. I have to study more how to use it.

Comment: I have edited my post; Can you be more specific on "it doesn't take the last one?". And about the second solution (which is better IMHO) what's the problem? I have tested that and it works fine here.

Comment: Hello. I have now added seconds to the filename. I use 2.7 IDLE shell to try the code. when running glob.glob("/home/pi/*.jgp") I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    last_photo_taken = glob.glob("/home/pi/*.jpg")[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You are missing the webcam dir part. Therevare no jpg files where you are scanning...

Comment: I deliberately skipped that directory for now. I guess a Python shell is by default starting from /home/pi (in Raspberry Pi)? In a linux terminal I have no problem to move around and start program from anywhere. If I put a python file elsewere I use to forget to start from there (if possible wit IDLE shell?)

Comment: start directory has nothing to do with it: you're using absolute paths.